# When is it appropriate to use df.value_counts() vs df.groupby('...').count()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've heard in Pandas there's often multiple ways to do the same thing, but I was wondering –

If I'm trying to group data by a value within a specific column and count the number of items with that value, when does it make sense to use `df.groupby('colA').count()` and when does it make sense to use `df['colA'].value_counts()` ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is difference [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) return:

> The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element.

but [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) not, it sort output by `index` (created by column in `groupby('col')`).

---

```
df.groupby('colA').count()
```

is for aggregate all columns of `df` by function `count.` So it count values excluding `NaN`s.

So if need `count` only one column need:

```
df.groupby('colA')['colA'].count()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colB':list('abcdefg'),
                   'colC':[1,3,5,7,np.nan,np.nan,4],
                   'colD':[np.nan,3,6,9,2,4,np.nan],
                   'colA':['c','c','b','a',np.nan,'b','b']})

print (df)
  colA colB  colC  colD
0    c    a   1.0   NaN
1    c    b   3.0   3.0
2    b    c   5.0   6.0
3    a    d   7.0   9.0
4  NaN    e   NaN   2.0
5    b    f   NaN   4.0
6    b    g   4.0   NaN

print (df['colA'].value_counts())
b    3
c    2
a    1
Name: colA, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('colA').count())
      colB  colC  colD
colA                  
a        1     1     1
b        3     2     2
c        2     2     1

print (df.groupby('colA')['colA'].count())
colA
a    1
b    3
c    2
Name: colA, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 22):

`Groupby` and `value_counts` are totally different functions. You cannot perform value_counts on a dataframe.

`Value Counts` are limited only for a single column or series and it's sole purpose is to return the series of frequencies of values

`Groupby` returns a object so one can perform statistical computations over it. So when you do `df.groupby(col).count()` it will return the number of true values present in columns with respect to the `specific columns` in groupby.

When should be `value_counts` used and when should  `groupby.count` be used : 
Lets take an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4], 'color': ["r","r","b","b","g","g","r"], 'size': [1,2,1,2,1,3,4]})
```

**Groupby count**:

```
df.groupby('color').count()
       id  size
color          
b       2     2
g       2     2
r       3     3
```

> Groupby count is generally used for getting the valid number of values
>   present in all the columns `with reference to` or `with respect to`  one 
>   or more columns specified. So not a number (nan) will be excluded.

*To find the frequency using groupby you need to aggregate against the specified column itself like @jez did. (maybe to avoid this and make developers life easy value_counts is implemented ).*

**Value Counts**:

```
df['color'].value_counts()

r    3
g    2
b    2
Name: color, dtype: int64
```

> Value count is generally used for finding the frequency of the values
>   present in one particular column.

In conclusion :

`.groupby(col).count()` should be used when you want to find the frequency of valid values present in columns with respect to specified `col`.

`.value_counts()` should be used to find the frequencies of a series.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good answers here, but I just wanted to add a more concise one:

```
df.value_counts('col')  # and its syntactic twin df['col'].value_counts()
```

is exactly identical to

```
df.groupby('col')['col'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Both approaches have some additional keyword parameters, but as I see it, the gist is that the former is pretty much just syntactic sugar for the latter, when you want to return a Series of the counts of each distinct item in `df[col]` in descending order.

The reasons to use `groupby(...).count()` are when you want to be able to count across multiple columns, or as part of a more complex aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

in simple words: `.value_counts()` Return a Series containing counts of **unique rows** in the DataFrame which means it counts up the individual values in a specific row and reports how many of the values are in the column:
imagine we have a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['John', 'Anne', 'John', 'Beth'],

                   'middle_name': ['Smith', pd.NA, pd.NA, 'Louise']})

first_name  middle_name
0   John    Smith
1   Anne    <NA>
2   John    <NA>
3   Beth    Louise
```

then we apply value_counts on it:

```
    df.value_counts()

first_name  middle_name
Beth        Louise         1
John        Smith          1
dtype: int64
```

as you can see it didn't count rows with NA values.
however `count()` count non-NA cells for each column or row.
in our example:

```
df.count()

first_name     4
middle_name    2
dtype: int64
```