# Why does groupby in Pandas place counts under existing column names?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm coming from R and do not understand the default groupby behavior in pandas. I create a dataframe and groupby the column 'id' like so:

```
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4], 'color': ["r","r","b","b","g","g","r"], 'size': [1,2,1,2,1,3,4]}
df = DataFrame(data=d)
freq = df.groupby('id').count()
```

When I check the header of the resulting dataframe, all the original columns are there instead of just 'id' and 'freq' (or 'id' and 'count').

```
list(freq)
Out[117]: ['color', 'size']
```

When I display the resulting dataframe, the counts have replaced the values for the columns not employed in the count:

```
freq
Out[114]: 
    color  size
id             
1       1     1
2       3     3
3       1     1
4       2     2
```

I was planning to use groupby and then to filter by the frequency column. Do I need to delete the unused columns and add the frequency column manually? What is the usual approach?

Comment: `When I check the header of the resulting dataframe` you are not doing that because you are doing `list(df)` not `list(freq)`. `list(freq)` does give `['color', 'size']`

Comment: To get the frequency of only one column use `value_counts()` rather than groupby.

Comment: fixed the code to list(freq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` aggregate all columns of `DataFrame` with excluding `NaN`s values, if need `id` as column use `as_index=False` parameter or `reset_index()`:

```
freq = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).count()
print (freq)
   id  color  size
0   1      1     1
1   2      3     3
2   3      1     1
3   4      2     2
```

So if add `NaN`s in each column should be differences:

```
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4], 
     'color': ["r","r","b","b","g","g","r"],
      'size': [np.nan,2,1,2,1,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

freq = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).count()
print (freq)
   id  color  size
0   1      1     0
1   2      3     3
2   3      1     1
3   4      2     2
```

You can specify columns for count:

```
freq = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['color'].count()
print (freq)
   id  color
0   1      1
1   2      3
2   3      1
3   4      2
```

If need `count` with `NaN`s:

```
freq = df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (freq)
   id  count
0   1      1
1   2      3
2   3      1
3   4      2
```

---

```
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4], 
     'color': ["r","r","b","b","g","g","r"],
      'size': [np.nan,2,1,2,1,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

freq = df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (freq)
   id  count
0   1      1
1   2      3
2   3      1
3   4      2
```

Thanks [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495337/why-does-groupby-in-pandas-place-counts-under-existing-column-names/47495345#comment81945920_47495345) for pointed for another solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), differences are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487816/2901002):

```
freq = df['id'].value_counts().rename_axis('id').to_frame('freq').reset_index()
print (freq)
   id  freq
0   2     3
1   4     2
2   3     1
3   1     1
```

Comment: Maybe Op is looking for `df['id'].value_counts().to_frame('freq')`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. This produces the answer I was looking for `freq = df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='count')`