# Facing an Error while creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Original dataframe :

```
df.head()
>
     beer_beerid    review_profilename    review_overall
0     48215          stcules                   3.0
1     52159          oline73                   3.0
2     52159          alpinebryant              3.0
3     52159          rawthar                   4.0
4     52159          RangerClegg               3.5
```

Need to create a new column with number of occurrence of beer_beerid in this dataframe. If beerid 52159 occurs 4 times - then the new column value for that beerid should be 4.

Used the below Code :

```
df['beer_review_count'] = df.groupby('beer_beerid').transform('count')
```

It gives the following error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Comment: what output you want in the resulting dataframe regarding 'beer_review_count' column, i mean what each cell contain in this row

Comment: check the output , number of rows might not be same....or datatype - it should be list or series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
df['beer_review_count'] = df.groupby('beer_beerid')['beer_beerid'].transform('count')
```

It works fine by using **transform()**

```
beer_beerid   profilename  overall  beer_review_count
0  48215       stcules      3.0                  1
1  52159       oline73      3.0                  4
2  52159  alpinebryant      3.0                  4
3  52159       rawthar      4.0                  4
4  52159   RangerClegg      3.5                  4
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the schema in the edit is the correct one,
Try

> df['beer_beerid'].value_counts()

Share a picture of the CSV file, just so that I can be sure as I right now  I am not sure if it is beerid or _beerid.

[LINK](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-get-frequency-counts-of-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe/)

```
df.groupby('beer_beerid')['beer_beerid'].count()
```

EDIT:

Possible fix to NaN error and unlike the other solution, this should avoid redundancies: the repeating of values.

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487753/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-df-value-counts-vs-df-groupby-count)

The output according to what I did should be this.

```
beer_beerid
48215       1 
52159       4
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/i-want-to-create-a-column-of-value-counts-in-my-pandas-dataframe) helps to add the column  to the existing dataframe.

Comment: its "beer_beerid"